# In Spider-Man, why does he first save Mary Jane, and not the children?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, spider-man-2002

In *Spider-Man (2002)* why does Spider-Man save Mary Jane first, choosing her over the 30-50 kids in the cable-car?

He eventually saves them both, but I'm just saying. What if he wasn't able to save them both?

Comment: Then presumably many or all of them would have died, and the movie would have had a very different plot. Might have been a better movie, who can say?

Comment: You appear to be asking two questions: "why does he save Mary Jane first?" and "what if he wasn't able to save them both?"  Which one do you want us to answer?  (spoiler alert: the second one has a fairly obvious answer)

Comment: If you're interested in the ethical issues, you might want to take a look at Derek Parfit's work - Reasons and Persons is nontrivial but ultimately gives a lot to think about - or else Peter Singer's.

Comment: There is an old adage, better to have saved the one you love and lost 30-50 random kids than the opposite of that scenario.

Comment: Hoes before shortys?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I don't think you actually need to throw away the name in title, given this isn'T a particularly significant element in the plot

Comment: @Gallifreyan: yeah, could be right there.

Comment: He saved her first because he loves her and wasn't doing the logical thing. If he wasn't able to save them both, he would have saved her and had the guilt of allowing a bunch of children to fall to their deaths.

Answer (score 4):

Peter saved them both because he could. He seems to have made a judgement that saving MJ wouldn't have affected his ability to save the cable-car.

The novelisation is a little clearer.

> *She plummeted, arms and legs pinwheeling, and suddenly Spider-Man was right there, tucking her under his right arm.*
>
> *"Hold on!" he shouted, even as he fired a web line that snagged the
> underside of the bridge's center span, and Mary Jane thought giddily,
> He chose me! right before she was over-whelmed with guilt over the
> fate of the plunging cable car.*
>
> *But Spider-Man wasn't done, not remotely.*
>
> *Suddenly he released his web line, and there was the cable of the car
> whipping past them. She could barely see it, but Spider-Man homed in
> on it as if he had radar. He shifted Mary Jane onto his back even as
> he grabbed the trailing cable. She let out a scream as the two of them
> were yanked down, hard, hopelessly at the mercy of the tram's weight.*
>
> *Then Spider-Man fired another web line at the underside of the bridge,
> and the white substance snared it, sticking with unbreakable adhesion.
> There below the span, the gondola slammed to a halt, bouncing up and
> down, kids and dads tumbling everywhere.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Spider-man: Official Novelisation](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Man_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: This excerpt needs more "Spider-Man"

Comment: @Gallifreyan - No-one has ever accused this book of being well-written. Then again, it's aimed at children and young adults so continually identifying who's doing what (and to who) is essential.